# How to sort out "RuntimeWarning: A physical pull up resistor is fitted on this channel!"?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-1

Yesterday everything was working fine, but today I ran the same code and I am getting the following error even though nothing has physically changed:

```
test3.py:8: RuntimeWarning: A physical pull up resistor is fitted on this channel!
  GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
test3.py:9: RuntimeWarning: A physical pull up resistor is fitted on this channel!
  GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
```

The code I am running is to operate a relay:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

# The script as below using BCM GPIO 00..nn numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Set relay pins as output
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)

# Time to sleep between operations in the main loop
SleepTimeS = 0.5

# Main Loop
try:
        while (True):

            # Turn all relays ON
            GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
            # Sleep for 5 seconds
            sleep(SleepTimeS)
            # Turn all relays OFF
            GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
            # Sleep for 5 seconds
            sleep(SleepTimeS)

# End program cleanly with keyboard
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Good bye!"
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I tried adding `pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN`but I just get the same error.

Comment: The "warning" seems quite clear; these pins are intended for I²C and have 1.8kΩ pullups installed. They can still be used for active low circuitry. Maybe `RPi.GPIO` just got updated to state the obvious.

Comment: I was playing with code yesterday so maybe that triggered something? I'm trying a fresh install to see, but yes, it could have been updated to state the obvious. It doesn't effect the operation, just sets off my OCD.

Comment: This warning also happens with inputs if you turn on the internal pullup: GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) If you're doing that, just let it use the external one that's there anyway: GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of choices.

- ignore the warning
- switch RPi.GPIO warnings off (see its documentation)
- don't use GPIO 2/3 (pins 3/5) which have the hard-wired pull-ups

Comment: If it happens again I think I will just turn off the warnings, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: 4th option: use the physical pullups instead of the software ones?! What are the specs of the hardware pullups?

Comment: All the GPIO were being used as outputs in the questioner's script.  Pulls are normally only used for inputs.  The external pull-ups on GPIO2/3 are both 1k8 in value.

Answer (score 0):

A fresh install of raspbian has fixed the issue, whatever I tinkered with yesterday must of activated the pull up resistors.

Comment: I'm afraid that is wrong.  The hard-wired resistors are ALWAYS enabled.

Comment: Strange how its reacted... I made sure to  update/upgrade/rpi-update before testing.

Comment: You can see the resistors on the circuit board next to pins 3 and 5.  Perhaps the fresh install has pre-installed an older version of RPi.GPIO.  I don't know when those particular warnings were introduced.

Comment: I thought they work using `pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP` so thanks for the info @joan :)

Comment: Each GPIO also has an internal pull-up to 3V3 and pull-down to ground which can be set with software.  I.e. each GPIO may have an internal pull-up, pull-down, or neither enabled.